# How can I make a health bar — a UI element — part of a character prefab?

Tags: unity, unity-ui, prefabs

### Description

I want my character prefabs to come with their own health bar, but I can't simply add one as part of the prefab, because it's a UI element and therefore goes into a Canvas.

### Potential Solution

I could write a script that takes in a separate health bar prefab and instantiates it when the character prefab's instantiated, but it's one extra script.

Is there a more conventional way to do this? I'd think this is a common problem.

Comment: As the UI element isn't directly part of the character (in a unity sense: they share no direct transform relation) it is not common practice to do so. Even if you did, you'd have to script a parent reassignment to a Canvas, which would be an additional script either way.

Comment: Also, for the sake of exploring an answer, how does this health bar appear on the UI?

Comment: Why you don't want the character to have its own ui canvas? If you use one single canvas for everything then your whole ui will be "recalculated" each time a single healthbar changes.

Comment: @WeckarE. I'm not quite sure what you mean. It just... sits under the character? And follows the character's movements, of course.

Comment: @Nikaas I didn't know that! I thought the fewer the canvases, the better. Still, there's going to be a good number of characters on-screen (up to about 30). Should I still go for that?